# How to find the center of gravity or center of mass of an irregular body with uniform mass distribution?

Tags: algorithm

Recently I was trying to solve a small AI problem but got stuck in between as I could not find the center of mass of the various bodies.
I was wondering if any one of you could help me out with this one.

Problem explanation: Assume that i have a 2D body which is very irregular in shape and has a uniform mass distribution throughout. It's like the body is made up of 'n' tiny particles each of unit mass and hence though the body is very irregular in shape but the mass distribution is uniform. How can I locate the center of mass or center of gravity of this body?

Avanish!!

Comment: Do you not know the definition of center of mass?  That answers this very question...

Comment: Note: Calling the kind of data you have "uniform density" is *wrong* unless the particles have uniform spacing. What you have here is a discrete distribution of particles of uniform mass. A very nearly trivial case, and one covered in every discussion of CoMs I've ever seen.

Comment: Yes Mr McKee, it's a trivial case and certainly COM discussion is never complete without it but my problem is a little diff as I donot have equation of those curves(body). 
This is not a problem from a mathematics text or physics text, I'm actually trying to use this technique in my problem where predicting any equation from the avaialble data(i.e co-ordinates) doesnot seems to be possible. Even I cannot use the curve fitting techniques here. By the way I would really appreciate your efforts if you can suggest me anyother way to either calculate the equation of the body or the COM.
Thanks!!

Comment: @Mr Blue Raja:Yes Mr.Raja, I'm aware of the concepts of center of mass. But please understand that this isn't a homework problem with enough data given.I can calculate COM using the co-ordinates but since there are more than a million such points so I ll be wasting machine's memory to perform those many calculations and the other way is by taking the summation (or integration) of the perticles but to proceed with that i atleast need to know the boundary eqn of the body and which also seems impossible in this case as what I know is just those coordinates.
Hope I'm more clear this time.
Thanks

Comment: You've been given the answer twice in math and once in imperative pseudocode. What else do want? Your is the *discrete* not *continuous* case so the "curves" are irrelevant and the answer is a sum not an integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I get it now. You have a *vast number* of discrete particles to work with. With emphasis on the **big** number.

Well, why didn't you say?

You can't do it exactly (i.e. without approximation) any faster than iterating though all the points. At least not without providing more relevant information.

[Adam's sampling suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2163478/edit) is a good way to obtain an approximation if you have random access to the data.

An alternative that won't be faster for a single operation, but might be useful if you are going to have to recalculate often is to reduce the working set to a smaller group of heavier points. Something like this:

1. Divide space into a grid of `N_x * N_y * N_z` cells of sizes `(l_x,l_y,L_z)`.
2. Compute the total mass and location of the center of mass for all the points in each cell.
3. Discard any cells with no points contained, and use the results as the new working set.

For this to represent an improvement, you'll want to have an average of 10 or more original points per cell, but not so many that the introduced grandularity washes out the signal you are looking for.

How best to do step 2 depends on how the original data is organized and on how much room you have in memory to store intermediate results. With lots of memory available:

- Prepare and initialize to zero four (N_x,N_y,N_z) arrays called `M`, `Rx`, `Ry`, and `Rz` (or one scalar array `M` and one vector array `R`, that depends on your implementation language)
- Walk the main list on time, incrementing the values in the appropriate cell for each mass
- Walk the intermediate arrays to figure the collected masses and locations.

With relatively little memory but lots of time available for pre-calculation you would walk the main list once for every cell (but if you have that kind of time you probable can just do this straight).

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Mckee, you are absolutely an authority on the subject. You have suggested a very fine way and I'm thankful for your efforts. Let me try to implement it. Thanking you once again. 
Thanks to Mr Adam as well.

Answer (score 5):

#### Calculating a polygon's center of mass:

Simplify your body into a polygon, [and find its centroid](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/polyarea/), because ([quoting wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass)):

> If an object has uniform density then
>   its center of mass is the same as the
>   centroid of its shape.

This approach is faster if there are lots of particles, uniformly distributed within the polygon.

#### Calculating the mean location of all particles:

If you're having `n` particles, calculate the mean of their X and Y coordinates; That's the center of mass.

[Quoting wikipedia again](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass):

> The center of mass  of a system of
>   particles is defined as the average of
>   their positions, weighted by their
>   masses:

[image]

Your particles have the same mass, so your denominator equals `n`. The code in [@tkerwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163455/how-to-find-the-center-of-gravity-or-center-of-mass-of-an-irregular-body-with-un/2163483#2163483) calculates that fraction.

This approach works well if you don't have too many particles.

**Edit:**

#### Probabilistic calculation:

If you have too many points to efficiently calculate their mean location, try picking up some random points. Calculating their mean location would give you an excellent approximation of the entire mean. The more points you pick, the better is your approximation - according to [the Law Of Large Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).

Comment: Thats a good way Mr. Adam but this approach isn't possible as the bodies are curvical in nature. I can say that the bodies are just like amoebas.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't make it clear earlier, actually 'n' tends to infinity. So, calculaion of mean is not possible too. Also to integrate it over the lenghth of the body I atleast need to know the equaion of the outer body but since the body is so irregular(amoeba) that i'm helpless with the equation as well.

Comment: If you do not define your body as a finite number of points or a closed polygon, you should update your question.

Comment: Yes Mr Kerwin, the body has finite no of points but these points are too many to be calculated individually.
I can say there are around 1 million  such points and it will be stupidity to perform calculations on every point.
I hope the question is more clear now.
Anyway Thanks for response.

Comment: Edited my answer to add the probabilistic approach.

Comment: I will try this approach too.I'm hopeful that this will work.
Thank you Mr. Adam for your kind efforts.

Answer (score 3):

The center of mass is the average position of each particle weighted by the mass of that particle.  Since your particles are of the same mass, you only need to take the average position.

That is:

```
center_x = 0
center_y = 0
for p in particles:
    center_x += p.x
    center_y += p.y
center_x /= len(particles)
center_y /= len(particles)
```